# Entity Framework Cannot insert explicit value for identity column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Customer Model :

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

Payment Model that has a Customer as property :

```
public class Payment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public Customer? Customer { get; set; }
}
```

DataAccess (DbContext) :

```
public class DataAccess : DbContext
{
    IConfiguration Configuration;

    public DataAccess(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
    }

    public DbSet<Customer>? Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Payment>? Payments { get; set; }
}
```

Service (CRUD Operations) :

```
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<DataAccess> ContextFactory;

    public TestService(IDbContextFactory<DataAccess> contextFactory)
    {
        ContextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public async Task Add(Payment entity)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                await context.Payments!.AddAsync(entity);
                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle the exception (log, rethrow, etc.)
            Console.WriteLine($"Error adding payment: {ex.Message}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<Customer>> GetAllCustomer()
    {
        using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            return await context.Customers!.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<Payment>> GetAllPayment()
    {
        using (var context = ContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
        {
            return await context.Payments!.Include(P =>   P.Customer).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Migration (Table Creation) :

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Customers",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Customers", x => x.Id);
    });
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Payments",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
        CustomerId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Payments", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Payments_Customers_CustomerId",
            column: x => x.CustomerId,
            principalTable: "Customers",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

I get this error when I try to insert a payment:

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Any help please

Comment: What does your SQL look like? By that i mean the SQL used to create the original Tables

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334012/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-table-when-identity

Comment: This may also be helpful if you want to override some of the functionality of EF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: if the ID is auto generated, the solution is to remove the ID set in your code...

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are trying to assign a value explicitly to a column where the database automatically assigns it.

You might try without set the value of **Id** for tables to understand the scenario

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173562/entity-framework-error-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-tabl) for more information

Comment: I checked the database In every table the Id column is Identity=True

Comment: Yes i mean in the code you don't try to set value for Id field. or set it to 0 and see

Comment: And also try these modelbuilder.entity<Payment>().haskey(t => t.Id); to specify the key:

modelbuilder.entity<tblproduct>().haskey(t => t.prodid);
to configure the property not being auto increment:

modelbuilder.entity<tblproduct>().property(t => t.prodid).valuegeneratednever();

Comment: No I didn't set any value for Payment.Id but  when I try to add payment that include Customer which is have an Id it give me error on Customer.Id

Comment: [Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int PaymentId { get; set; }

Try this way in both tables and see

Comment: @IRAQIAIRWAYS - _when I try to add payment that include Customer which is have an Id it give me error on Customer.Id_ - this information must be in question. Edit it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).